# Get all element contain or not some class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html structure like

```
<div class="dv a">a</div>
<div class="dv a">a1</div>
<div class="dv b">b</div>
<div class="dv b">b1</div>
<div class="dv c">c</div>
<div class="dv c">c1</div>
<div class="dv d">d</div>
<div class="dv d">d1</div>
```

How can i get all element contain a or b or c class

```
$(".dv").each(function(){}); /// ? how to get
```

And how to get all element not contain a or b class

```
$(".dv:not(.a|.b)").each(function() {}); // ?how to get
```

Comment: Just checking: you want all of the elements whose class is `a` or `b` or `c`, but you don’t care about class `dv`? If so, then the selector `.a,.b,.c` is the correct one. If you want only the ones with class `dv` then it’s a little more.

Comment: @Manngo Hi, I want them with `dv` class

Comment: Have you tried `$('.dv').find('.a,.b,.c')` ? This first finds the `dv` class, and then filters only the ones which match the second selector.

Comment: As regards the `not`, this may or may not work: `.dv:not(.a,.b,.c)`. If it doesn’t, you could try `.dv:not(.a):not(.b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about jQuery is that it can take advantage of your skills in CSS, provided that the browser is up to date. If it is, then the following pure CSS selectors will do the job:

```
.dv.a, .dv.b, .dv.c {           /*  Matching Ones: */

}

.dv:not(.a):not(.b):not(.c) {   /*  Non Matching Ones: */

}
```

The following snippet will illustrate this:

```css
.dv.a, .dv.b, .dv.c {
  color: red;
}

.dv:not(.a):not(.b):not(.c) {
  border: thin solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dv a">a</div>
<div class="dv a">a1</div>
<div class="dv b">b</div>
<div class="dv b">b1</div>
<div class="dv c">c</div>
<div class="dv c">c1</div>
<div class="dv d">d</div>
<div class="dv d">d1</div>
```

Comment: thank, love use like css `.dv.a, .dv.b, .dv.c` do the trick :)

Comment: @DeLe Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

To select with `or` logic:

```
$( ".a, .b, .c" )
```

To select with `not` logic:

```
$( "div:not(.a, .b)" )
```

To select all `.dv` but without `.d`:

```
$( ".dv:not(.d)" )
```

Here's a snippet that counts all logics with the selectors above:

```js
var orCount = $( ".a, .b, .c" ).length;
var andCount = $( "div:not(.a, .b)" ).length;
var notdCount = $( ".dv:not(.d)" ).length;

console.log('or logic count = ' + orCount);
console.log('and logic count = ' + andCount);
console.log('not d logic count = ' + notdCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dv a">a</div>
<div class="dv a">a1</div>
<div class="dv b">b</div>
<div class="dv b">b1</div>
<div class="dv c">c</div>
<div class="dv c">c1</div>
<div class="dv d">d</div>
<div class="dv d">d1</div>
```

Comment: thankiu, but `or` logic i want with `.dv` class like `$( ".dv:(.a, .b, .c)" )` ?

Comment: Than you should use `not`, not `or` : `$( ".dv:not(.d)" )`